# snake identification

Tags: species-identification, herpetology

While moving large, old oak logs I'd stacked a year ago to form a terraced garden, I noticed it was very moist under the logs.

I saw 5 kingsnakes, a scarlet snake,  a couple of small brown earth snakes and an **unidentified snake**:

- Thicker body than the King snakes, very skinny head, 3-4 feet long, and  almost all brown.

Can you identify the snake?

[image]

<sup>Note: Picture taken from about 10 feet away. The debris on the snake pictured is sawdust and wood pieces.</sup>

We catch, picture and release kingsnakes, rat snakes and hog nosed snakes all the time, but this one escaped before capture or a good picture. Only one copperhead in 18 years.

Location: Gasconade County, MO (USA; 1 mile from Rosebud, MO).

- We have a 1.5 acre pond about 80 yards from the picture site.